# Is it okay for a class to have a field of its own type

Tags: java, oop, object

I did the following, i got a stackoverflow error after some time, and I understand why it was.

```
public class Cat {
    String name="default name";
    Cat insideCat;

    public Cat(){
         System.out.println("Cat constructor");
         insideCat = new Cat();
    }

}
```

But what if I don't create a new Cat object within the constructor, but take a parameter of Cat type and assign it to the insideCat field.

```
public class Cat {
    String name="default name";
    Cat insideCat;

    public Cat(Cat insideCat){
         System.out.println("Cat constructor");
         this.insideCat = insideCat;
    }

}
```

I am just playing around with the code, just trying to find out what Java can do and cannot. In the second code, everything looked normal, until I started to test this class. I need a Cat object to create a Cat object (and to create this Cat object I need another Cat object...and it goes on). So technically I cannot test this class.

So my question is WHY does java allow to create an instance variable of its own type? I guess the whole purpose of a constructor is to initialize it's instance variables. So either I have to create a new object to initialize the insideCat or else I have to take Cat object from outside. Both doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing here. Is there any occurrence where instance variables of its own types can become useful, and can be used without any problem? Is it bad OOP practice to come up with classes like this?

Comment: How would you implement a doubly linked list?

Comment: It is fine to have a field of the same type, but the creation of child objects has to stop somehow. Your child objects are created unconditionally.

Comment: You can easily test this class by passing `null` into your very first `Cat(...)` constructor. You can then provide a way to assign something else to `insideCat` later if you wish.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Classes like this exist all the time.

Consider linked lists or trees, e.g.,

```
class ListNode {
  ListNode next;
  // Etc.
}

class TreeNode {
  TreeNode left;
  TreeNode right;
  // Etc.
}
```

You wouldn't initialize the "child" objects in the constructor, you'd add them later.

In your example you'd need to have a method that created the `insideCat` at a later time. In general you wouldn't create child objects that had the exact same state, there'd be something to differentiate them either at construction time, in which case you could have a "oh god stop creating these now" condition, or while they were being added, e.g., you'd add them via a method and not in a constructor.

Comment: i have read the whole purpose of a constructor is to initialize its instance variables, so am I not breaking that by initializing those special fields in a new method?

Comment: @DesirePRG The "whole purpose" of a ctor is to construct an object. Instance variables may not be in their final state during construction. In a list example the `next` value may not even *exist* until it's added to the list. The list itself would take care of finding the last list node, setting its `next` to the new list item, etc. In that case all a `ListNode` needs to do is have `next` be either `null` or a null object.

Comment: Okay, so is it correct if i say, that a constructor can initialize a chosen set of its instance variables, and keep the rest as null ( let's assume i have only object fields), until initializing those make sense!

Comment: And about your point on constructor, an abstract class can still have a constructor but it cannot construct an object. So can we say that a constructor's purpose is to construct an object?

Comment: @DesirePRG Yes; a ctor will only initialize what it makes sense to initialize. I think saying "a constructor's purpose is to construct an object" is... obvious. Abstract classes must be extended to be used; the ctor of the abstract class may still be used to construct the child class instance. You *cannot* use an abstract class's ctor unless you extend it: its purpose is still to construct a class; that additional semantics are necessary to do so seems irrelevant.

Comment: well.. I think that makes it all clear! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong in having an instance member of same class. 
an Employee has a manager and the manager is also an Employee

```
 public class Employee{
     private Employee manager;
     //getters setters and constructor
 }
```

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't understand why I couldn't think of the example you provided in the answer :) An obvious upvote from my side

Answer (score 3):

There are many examples of self referencing data structures that are valid.  Think of a `LinkedList`.  Each `LinkNode` has a data field, and a pointer to the next `LinkNode`.

```
class LinkNode {
    int data;
    LinkNode nextLink;

    public LinkNode(int d1) {
        data = d1;
        nextLink = null;
    }
    ...
}

class LinkedList {
    private LinkNode first;
...
}
```

Your `StackOverflow` problem stems from the fact that creating an instead of `X` requires the creation of another X`,` ad-infinitum.

Just think of your `Cat` example.  Why would instantiating a Cat require of all things...another `Cat`!

Comment: Instantiating a cat *does* require other cats ;) The example here is backwards from biology, though, and presupposes the existence of a neonatal cat at birth.

Comment: I disagree.  You can have a method called 'consumate' that returns a reference to the new Cat...But it doesn't have to happen in the constructor of the baby Cat.

Comment: Exactly: a cat that's pre-pregnant doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I see - we are agreeing in principle about the constructor here.

Comment: I know my class doesn't make sense in real life. I just wanted an example and randomly named it as "Cat"

Comment: @DesirePRG I was just being funny.

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple constructors. Thus, you can have another constructor

```
public Cat(){...}
```

That would allow you to create an inside Cat. Afterwards you could create another Cat that contains the inside Cat. Obviously, the design might not be great here, depending on your needs. Dave Newton's answer about linked list is a great real world example of this usage.